# MySQL insertar registros que no estén en la misma tabla

Tags: mysql

Tengo estos 4 registros como ven a continuación.

```
-----fecha---
2018/03/01 0:05
2018/03/01 0:15
2018/03/01 0:20
--------------
```

Están registrados en MySQL con su respectivo id.

Necesito que desde MySQL si existe un método o algo
que me muestre los registros que no coincidan

Por ejemplo tengo varios registros esos registros van en 5 minutos a 5 minutos como se ve en  la tabla, lo que quiero hacer es que MySQL me muestre el registro que no esta hay por ejemplo no esta el `2018/03/01 0:10` y que solo muestre ese

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Hola Jose carlos, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español y enhorabuena por tu primera publicación. Completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el funcionamiento general del sitio, y lee [ask] donde encontrarás consejos para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas (y reciban una mejor atención). Un saludo.

Comment: vas a tener que crear todos los registros (pero todos) y despues cruzar las tablas..

Answer (score 0):

Estos pasos te permitirán ver los registros donde la diferencia de hora supera los 5 minutos, estoy asumiendo que los id de las fechas son consecutivos, cree una tabla con los registros id y fecha

Si los id tienen valores consecutivos:

```
select * from tabla;

id  fecha
1   2018-03-01 00:05:00
2   2018-03-01 00:10:00
3   2018-03-01 00:15:00
4   2018-03-01 00:20:00
5   2018-03-01 00:25:00
```

Puedes ver los registros con id impar (desde id=1) con:

```
select ((id+1)/2) as id_1,fecha as fecha2 from tabla WHERE (id % 2)<>0;

 id_1   fecha2  
1.0000  2018-03-01 00:05:00
2.0000  2018-03-01 00:15:00
3.0000  2018-03-01 00:25:00
```

y los registros con id par (desde id=2) con:

```
select (id/2) as id_1,fecha as fecha1 from tabla WHERE (id % 2)=0;

 id_1   fecha1  
1.0000  2018-03-01 00:10:00
2.0000  2018-03-01 00:20:00
```

Las consultas crean un nuevo id (id_1) que es consecutivo y permite las comparaciones de las fechas

Para ver las diferencias de fechas entre registros consecutivos impares a pares (empezando desde el id_1) puedo ejecutar la siguiente sentencia:

```
select t1.id_1,fecha1,fecha2,(fecha2-fecha1) as diferencia
from (select ((id+1)/2) as id_1,fecha as fecha1 from tabla WHERE (id % 2)<>0) as t1,
(select (id/2) as id_1,fecha as fecha2 from tabla WHERE (id % 2)=0) as t2
where t1.id_1=t2.id_1

 id_1   fecha1  fecha2  diferencia  
1.0000  2018-03-01 00:05:00     2018-03-01 00:10:00     500
2.0000  2018-03-01 00:15:00     2018-03-01 00:20:00     500
```

Allí puedo ver si en algún registro la diferencia es superior a 500 (mayor a 5 minutos)

Si quiero ver las diferencias de fechas entre los registros de id pares a impares empezando desde id=2, tendría que hacer la siguiente sentencia:

```
select t1.id_1,fecha1,fecha2,(fecha2-fecha1) as diferencia
from (select (id/2) as id_1,fecha as fecha1 from tabla WHERE (id % 2)=0) as t1,
(select ((id+1)/2-1) as id_1,fecha as fecha2 from tabla WHERE (id % 2)<>0 and id > 1) as t2
where t1.id_1=t2.id_1;

 id_1   fecha1  fecha2  diferencia  
1.0000  2018-03-01 00:10:00     2018-03-01 00:15:00     500
2.0000  2018-03-01 00:20:00     2018-03-01 00:25:00     500
```

Uniendo las dos tablas anteriores:

```
select * from
(select t1.id_1,fecha1,fecha2,(fecha2-fecha1) as diferencia
from (select id as id_1,fecha as fecha1 from tabla WHERE (id % 2)<>0) as t1,
(select (id-1) as id_1,fecha as fecha2 from tabla WHERE (id % 2)=0) as t2
where t1.id_1=t2.id_1
UNION
select t1.id_1,fecha1,fecha2,(fecha2-fecha1) as diferencia
from (select id as id_1,fecha as fecha1 from tabla WHERE (id % 2)=0) as t1,
(select ((id+1)/2-1)*2 as id_1,fecha as fecha2 from tabla WHERE (id % 2)<>0 and id > 1) as t2
where t1.id_1=t2.id_1) as tabla_diferencias order by id_1

id_1    fecha1  fecha2  diferencia  
1   2018-03-01 00:05:00     2018-03-01 00:10:00     500
2   2018-03-01 00:10:00     2018-03-01 00:15:00     500
3   2018-03-01 00:15:00     2018-03-01 00:20:00     500
4   2018-03-01 00:20:00     2018-03-01 00:25:00     500
```

Así puedes finalmente ver la diferencia de los registros de fechas consecutivos y saber si alguna es mayor a 5 minutos

Comment: eso quiere decir que tengo que hacer 2 tablas una aquella que voy a comparar y la otra con todos los datos , pense que existia algun inner join que hiciera todo eso sin tener que registrar tantos datos, es que son muchas fechas y quiere decir que tengo que hace ren la otra tabla todos los meses del año y hora y y minutos

Comment: ¿tienes una muestra de la tabla donde están las fechas que quieres comparar?

Comment: no pero no es una comparacion si no es un insertar de las fechas que no esten